# Summarizing dataframe based on multiple columns

Tags: r, aggregate, summarize

I'm having some trouble figuring this one out. Say, I have a table like this:

```
    Name Activity Day
1   John    cycle   1
2   John     work   1
3   Tina     work   1
4 Monika     work   1
5   Tina     swim   1
6   Tina  jogging   2
7   John     work   2
8   Tina     work   2
```

I want to summarize it in a way that the activity of each individual is grouped according to the day.

It should look like this:

```
    Name      Activity Day
1   John    cycle;work   1
2   Tina     work;swim   1
3 Monika          work   1
4   Tina  jogging;work   2
5   John          work   2
```

I am thinking that `dplyr` package would be the answer here, but I don't know how to do it. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- tribble(~"Name", ~"Activity", ~"Day",
   "John",    "cycle",   1,
   "John",     "work" ,  1,
   "Tina",     "work",   1,
 "Monika",    "work",   1,
   "Tina",     "swim",   1,
   "Tina",  "jogging",   2,
   "John",     "work",   2,
   "Tina",     "work",  2)

dat %>% 
  group_by(Name, Day) %>% 
  summarise(activity = paste(Activity, collapse = "; "))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   Name [3]
  Name     Day activity     
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>        
1 John       1 cycle; work  
2 John       2 work         
3 Monika     1 work         
4 Tina       1 work; swim   
5 Tina       2 jogging; work
```

Comment: Thanks, @CoreyPembleton. I have tried that before, but it doesn't seem to work. It does return all the combinations for `Name` and `Day`, but it does not aggregate the `Activity` values.

Comment: @Douglas I've updated the anser, it now gives the result you want in a "tidy" way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `aggregate` function, for example:

```
> aggregate(dat$Activity,list(dat$Name,dat$Day),as.character)
  Group.1 Group.2             x
1    John       1   cycle, work
2  Monika       1          work
3    Tina       1    work, swim
4    John       2          work
5    Tina       2 jogging, work
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .(Activity = toString(Activity)), .(Name, Day)]
```